# How to restore developer unlock for Windows Phone 7

Tags: 7.8

My HTC Radar with Windows Phone 7.8 had student developer unlock. Recently, I made reset to factory settings. So, unlock was lost.

Is it possible to restore that unlock?

Comment: Are you open to unlocking the bootloader and using a custom ROM? It's been a long time since I thought about WP7 - it's pretty much a dead platform at this point, you really ought to upgrade - but I *think* there were custom ROMs for the radar and they all come developer-unlocked (and interop-unlocked, and usually full-unlocked for arbitrary native EXE execution too).

Comment: @CBHacking I don't know, previously I just used special Microsoft  developer software for making developer unlock

Answer (score 0):

Use the Developer Registration program that comes with the [Windows Phone 7.8 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474) to developer unlock your HTC Radar.

Comment: Microsoft shut down the developer unlock service for WP7 (and even for 8.0, I believe) many years ago. The developer registration program just always reports an error and asks you to check your clock (I suspect it may be simply an expired certificate they never bothered to re-issue).